# Displaying VUE CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-i18n

**I can't display v-for using CDN**

```
const Gallery = { template: '{{$t('gallery')}} <img :class="[[item.class]]" v-for="(item, index) in carousel" :src="[[item.img]]" alt="img" />' }

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Gallery }
];

// CDN app.use(i18n);
// CDN app.use(router)
// CDN app.mount("#app");
```

I can't show the following v-for using Vue View CDN

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but to me the provided string for your template should be formatted with double quotes around single quotes:

```
const Gallery = { template: "{{$t('gallery')}} <img :class='[[item.class]]' v-for='(item, index) in carousel' :src='[[item.img]]' alt='img' />" }
```

Could you please provide more context? Error output, etc...?